# How do I create a custom date format in footer that updates automatically in Powerpoint 2007?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, date-time

I see how to add a date to the footer that updates automatically, either via "Insert->Header&Footer" or "Insert->Date&Time". Works great!

However, I can't figure out how to do this with a custom date format (for example, just the year "yyyy"). I had thought maybe I could create a field in Word that used a custom date format and copy and paste it into my PP document, but that didn't work.

Comment: After a quick look for a way to do this, I cant seem to help you. Im very surprised that a simple option like this could have been missed out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll need to do a macro for this. I remember seeing something similar in Excel. I couldn't find the article I saw a couple of years ago, but I did find this one for Excel [Excel Article](http://excel.tips.net/Pages/T003377_Putting_a_Different_Date_in_a_Header.html)

I'm not a programmer, but you may know someone who is or maybe someone from here can help you with the exact language. Still, I think a macro is the vehicle you'll have to use and the language contained in that article should help your programmer put it together. I hope this helps.

Comment: I think you are right.  A 'one liner' will do the job: Sub AddCustomDateToSlideMasterFooter()
    ActivePresentation.SlideMaster.HeadersFooters.Footer.Text = Format(Now(), "yyyy")
End Sub